# Wix Installer Customization

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I am working on new Wix for creating exe for my WPF application. But now I have a situation where single installer has to install multiple exe lying in different folder with option to install or not to install particular exe by a checkbox just like in MS office installtion. I could not find an example on web. Can some one guide me to where to start from so that I can have some begining push ?
[image]

Comment: I have a few links here: https://github.com/frederiksen/WPF-WiX-Bootstrapper